# What is my flaw in this derivative problem?

Tags: calculus

I want to derivate the following function:

$y=\frac{3x-1}{5-2x}$

Using the general derivative formula

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{f(x+h)-f(x)}{h}$

So I started off like this:

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{3(x+h)-1}{5-2(x+h)}-\frac{3x-1}{5-2x}}{h}$

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{3x+3h-1}{5-2x+2h}-\frac{3x-1}{5-2x}}{h}$

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{\frac{17h-12xh}{4x^2-4xh-20x+10h+25}}{h}$

$\lim_{h\to 0} \frac{17-12x}{(5-2x)^2}$

But I know this is not right because if I try it the other way I get:

$\frac{d}{dx}\frac{3x-1}{5-2x}=\frac{\frac{d}{dx}(3x-1)(5-2x)-\frac{d}{dx}(5-2x)(3x-1)}{(5-2x)^2}=\frac{13}{(5-2x)^2}$

What do I need to change in my method?

Comment: There is a mistake in the first step itself. The point is, when you write $f(x+h)$, then wherever $x$ is present in the expression $f(x)$, you must substitute $x+h$. What you have written is $f(x) + h$, which is incorrect. $f(x+h) = \frac{3(x+h)-1}{5-2(x+h)}$ is the right expression.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$f(x)=\frac{3x-1}{5-2x}\implies f(x+h)=\frac{3(x+h)-1}{5-2(x+h)}$$ $$f(x+h)-f(x)=\frac{3(x+h)-1}{5-2(x+h)}-\frac{3x-1}{5-2x}$$ Reduce to same denominator, simplify by expansion the resulting numerator to get $$f(x+h)-f(x)==\frac{13 h}{(2 x-5) (2 x+2 h-5)}$$

Answer (score 0):

In the second step should be $5-2x-2h$ not $5-2x+2h$.